# Stop coordinate labels overlapping on tikzpicture graph

Tags: pgfplots, labels

I am plotting a graph on tikz and the labels for each coordinate (the reference in this case) are overlapping as the points are close together. Is there a way for me to define what anchor position each label gets for each point?

Thanks!

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
grid,
xmode=log,
ymode=log,
xmin=0, xmax=1000,
ymin=1000, ymax=10000000000,
xlabel={Carrier Mobility/ cm$^2$(Vs)$^{-1}$},
ylabel={I$_{ON}$/I$_{OFF}$}
]

\addplot+ [every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny,color=black}, nodes near coords,  only marks, point meta=explicit symbolic]
table[meta=label]{
x   y   label
217 100000000   \cite{radisavljevic2011single}
11  100000  \cite{kang2014high}
36.4    1000000 \cite{wu2016high}
11.3    1000000 \cite{ahn2017ambient}   
6   1000000000  \cite{amani2013electrical}
16.1    10000000    \cite{amani2013electrical}
80  10000   \cite{yu2016design}
17  100000000   \cite{wu2013high}
25  10000000    \cite{nourbakhsh2016mos2}
21  10000000    \cite{fang2018controlled}   
12.24   1000000 \cite{choudhary2016synthesis}
16.1    100000000   \cite{hong2015exploring}    
9.5 100000000   \cite{kumar2023optoelectronic}
10  10000000    \cite{liu2019ambipolar}
44.8    10000000    \cite{chen2018dramatic}
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Current result of code.]

Comment: Welcome. You can use the [`.condition` handler](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-2dplots#pgfp./pgfplots/nodes:near:coords) with `coordinate style`, for example: `coordinate style/.condition={\coordindex==3}{below}`.

Comment: related? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/634707/how-to-place-point-labels-in-a-tikz-scatter-plot

Answer (score 2):

Mixing together several answers here, like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/634731/38080) and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47692/38080) --- I use a scatter plot; I added the class to change the color of the points just to identify them, and then added the anchor depending on a column in the table. You have to change that manually --- this is the anchor point range of the label; `0` means that the label will be on the left, `-90` above, and so on.

I haven't the references, so all is `[?]` here; you probably need to manually adjust the label position when the real numbers go in.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        grid,
        xmode=log,
        ymode=log,
        xmin=2, xmax=1000, %<---- you can't have "0" here for xmode=log
        ymin=1000, ymax=1e10,
        xlabel={Carrier Mobility (\unit{\cm\squared\per\volt\per\second})},
        ylabel={I$_{\mathit{ON}}$/I$_{\mathit{OFF}}$} %<- it's the word OFF, not O multiplied F multiplied F...
        ]
        \addplot [every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny,color=black, 
                anchor=\Anchor},
            scatter/classes={a={blue}, b={red}},
            scatter, mark=*, only marks,
            scatter src=explicit symbolic,
            nodes near coords*={\Label},
            visualization depends on={value \thisrow{label} \as \Label},
            visualization depends on={value \thisrow{anchor} \as \Anchor},
            ]
            table[meta=class]{
                x      y    label                           class  anchor
                217    1e8  \cite{radisavljevic2011single}  a      -90
                11     1e5  \cite{kang2014high}             a      -90
                36.4   1e6  \cite{wu2016high}               a      -90
                11.3   1e6  \cite{ahn2017ambient}           a      -90
                6      1e9  \cite{amani2013electrical}      a      -90
                16.1   1e7  \cite{amani2013electrical}      a      -90
                80     1e4  \cite{yu2016design}             a      -90
                17     1e8  \cite{wu2013high}               b      180
                25     1e7  \cite{nourbakhsh2016mos2}       a      -90
                21     1e7  \cite{fang2018controlled}       b       90
                12.24  1e6  \cite{choudhary2016synthesis}   b      180
                16.1   1e8  \cite{hong2015exploring}        a      -90
                9.5    1e8  \cite{kumar2023optoelectronic}  a      -90
                10     1e7  \cite{liu2019ambipolar}         a      -90
                44.8   1e7  \cite{chen2018dramatic}         a      -90
            };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I reformatted everything a bit, used scientific notation (I got lost with the number of zeroes ), and used `siunitx` for the units.

[image]